# SQL Server 2014 - Query to skip rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that has the following fields (Institution, Auditor, QuestionID, Comment). There are 5 different questions (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and an Auditor will have made a comment/response on each question.

I need to return only those rows where an auditor has made a comment on at least one question. If no comment has been made on any question then that row needs to be skipped. So for example if Auditor 1 has made a comment on Q1 for Institution 1 then we need to see all 5 rows for Auditor 1 for that institution. If another Auditor has not made any comments yet on any questions for an institution that Auditors records for that institution needs to be skipped.

[image]

In the image above we should return the following data and skip the one shaded green because there are no comments entered for Institution B by Auditor A2 for any question

[image]

I am confused how I can do this. Maybe keep a count? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It would be good to provide the DDL, DML and the expected output so that its easier to work on this solution.

Comment: In general we can use analytical functions to get the count(*) over(partition by Institution,Auditor) --> by auditor and by Institution and then filter out the ones we dont want and the ones we want to keep

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What is a row?  How are different questions represented?

Comment: Added the data and desired result. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like `exists` to me.  It is a little hard to follow your description of the data.  But based on your example, I think:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.auditor = t.auditor and
                    t2.institution = t.institution and
                    t2.comment is not null
             );
```